# PouchDB.sync throw error : ETIMEDOUT frequently

Tags: pouchdb

I found in slow network connection and with large documents/attachments, the PouchDB.sync will throw a timeout error: ETIMEDOUT !

My code is simple, just sync data from remote CouchDB to local browser PouchDB.

```
this._getDBServer()
                .then(db => {
                    return db.sync(dbLocalURL)
                })
                .then(result => {
                    log.debug('%s:sync ok',label,result)
                    resolve(true)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    log.warn('%s:sync error:',label,e)
                    resolve(false)
                })
```

And the [doc](https://pouchdb.com/errors.html#replicating_attachments_slow) on PouchDB.com can partly resolve this problem. According to the doc, I adjust the "batch_size", "batch_limit" two options to 1, and the result is better, I got less error, but can not remove it completely.

I tracked the source code, its here throw error:

```
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
  var data;
  if (options.binary) {
    data = createBlob([xhr.response || ''], {
      type: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
    });
  } else {
    data = xhr.responseText;
  }
  callback(null, response, data);
} else {
  var err = {};
  if (timedout) {
    err = new Error('ETIMEDOUT');
    err.code = 'ETIMEDOUT';
  } else if (typeof xhr.response === 'string' && xhr.response !== '') {
    try {
      err = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  err.status = xhr.status;

  callback(err);
}
```

the timeout value here is the default value: 10000, if I directly change the timeout value to 60000, then the error will not throw, so I think the problem is my documents have too many attachments to sync, it will cause to timeout in slow network.

So how can I resolve this problem? Is there any other way to avoid the error? Or I should set the XHR timeout longer? If so, where is the right place to set it?

My PouchdDB version: 6.4.3
My CouchDB version: 2.1.2